# Compare strings with different encodings

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, string, unicode

I'm trying to compare a string from a file that is encoded in UTF8

```
file /dev/eeprom: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines
```

with a serial number that is hardcoded into the script.
When printing to the console, the string appears just fine but it seems there is a problem with the format of the file (iconv isn't available though).
The script is an ASCII text executable if file output is correct.

```
#!/bin/sh
eeprom_id=$(cat /dev/eeprom | grep -e ID: | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[2]}')
echo "EEPROM_ID: $eeprom_id"

if [ $eeprom_id == "C000139-102" ]
then
    echo "String identical"
else
    echo "WRONG"
fi
```

Output:

```
.script.sh
EEPROM_ID: C000139-102
WRONG
```

Any ideas how to compare those strings properly?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you post the output of `cat /dev/eeprom` (at least the relevant line with the ID). It is very likely that the entire script can be replaced by a single `awk` call, but we would need to see the reference.

Comment: @AdminBee better `cat -A /dev/eeprom`. I suspect that it's in UTF-16, e.g. each character followed by a NUL (`I\0D\0` instead of `ID`). The NUL bytes are "invisible" on a terminal.

Comment: `==` in the test command `[...] ` should be `=`

Comment: ... but, except for Zsh, all common Bourne-like shells don't allow null bytes to survive command substitution.

Comment: What's the output of `od -vtx1 -tc /dev/eeprom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to do this entirely in `awk`:

```
awk -F':' -v ref_id="C000139-102" '$1=="ID" {if ($2==ref_id) print "Identical"; else print "WRONG"}' /dev/eeprom
```

To read out the ID into a shell variable, as in your example script:

```bsh
eeprom_id=$(awk -F':' '$1=="ID" {print $2}')
```

---

If, as @user414777 suspects, you are dealing with UTF-16-encoded file, you may have to use

```
cat /dev/eeprom | tr -d '\0' | awk -F':' -v ref_id="C000139-102" '$1=="ID" {if ($2==ref_id) print "Identical"; else print "WRONG"}'
```

or try

```
awk -F':' -v ref_id="C000139-102" '{gsub(/\x00/,""); if ($1=="ID") {if ($2==ref_id) print "Identical"; else print "WRONG"}}' /dev/eeprom
```

Again, to read the ID into a shell variable:

```
eeprom_id=$(cat /dev/eeprom | tr -d '\0' | awk -F':' '$1=="ID" {print $2}')
```

or

```
eeprom_id=$(awk -F':' '{gsub(/\x00/,""); if ($1=="ID") print $2}' /dev/eeprom)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot!

__eeprom_id=$(cat /dev/eeprom | tr -d '\0' | awk -F':' '$1=="ID" {print $2}')__

Comment: @DK999 You're welcome. Out of curiosity: Would it also work if you used the last example `awk` program, where I used `gsub()` instead of piping the file through `tr`, or did you encounter errors there?

Comment: Works also just fine :3

Comment: @DK999 Ok, thanks for the update!